# Lambda function Python 3.6 to shut off EC2 instance with specific tags

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Here is what I have so far. I just need help creating if statement/for loop for comparing tags. My tags are: Key: 'Name', Value: 'TestServer'. Thanks!

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
#tag = ec2.Tag('i-018b3ee8dd8b9fed3','Name','TestServer1')

region = 'us-east-1'
instances = ['i-018b3ee8dd8b9fes4']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances )
    print('stopped your instances: ' + str(instances) +str(tag))
```

Comment: FYI, I created a [Simple EC2 Stopinator in Lambda - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/simple-ec2-stopinator-in-lambda-5goj) that can stop/terminate instances based on tag. Feel free to use the code.

Comment: I tried but it does not seem to work could you post it down below :). I tried to create a JSON policy that would specify only to allow the stopping or starting based on certain tags but I need to filter out tags more specifically for tags I dont want etc..

Comment: import boto3
region = 'us-east-1'
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
instances = ['i-018b3ee8dd8b9fes5']


def lambda_handler(event,context):
 
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)

Comment: Thats what I have and it works. I have tried many different variations of filters, sorting by keys, etc.. and nothing seems to work. I am still sort of new so trying to learn but am getting upset when code that would normally work will not compile :(

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a filter based on your tags requirement and run the query, eventually iterate through the resource.

```py
import boto3
# Connect to EC2
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
 

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    custom_filter = [{
        'Name':'tag:Name', 
        'Values': ['TestServer']}]
    instances_to_stop = []
    running_instances = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=custom_filter)
    for reservation in running_instances.get('Reservations'):
        for instance in reservation.get('Instances'):
            instances_to_stop.append(instance.get('InstanceId'))
    print(f'Stopping following instance Ids : {instances_to_stop}')
    response = ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances_to_stop)
    print(response)
```

`Response`:

```json
{
  "StoppingInstances": [
    {
      "CurrentState": {
        "Code": 64,
        "Name": "stopping"
      },
      "InstanceId": "i-011ac4a33afdsadasd",
      "PreviousState": {
        "Code": 16,
        "Name": "running"
      }
    }
  ],
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "35a3ab",
      "date": "Thu, 04 Feb 2021 16:35:38 GMT",
      "server": "AmazonEC2"
    },
    "RetryAttempts": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: is that python 3.7 or 3.6 im using 3.6 and got some errors currently debugging and tidying up. Also, shouldn't the tag 'Name' field be Key??

Comment: ec2.stop_instances*

Comment: @robby I just typed the code here, to give nudge you in the correct direction. When you prepare the filter you provide the tags in the above format. Like `filters = [{'Name':'tag:environment', 'Values':[Env]},
           {'Name':'tag:role', 'Values':[Role]}
          ]`

Comment: actually it says im not able to use filter parameter in ec2.stop_instances... :( thanks for the help! if you can think of anything else please let me know!

Comment: @robby [stop_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.stop_instances) doesnt support `custom filters`. In my code above I am pasing `Instances`

Comment: I think i got it but my tags are Key: 'Name', Value: TestServer. So how would i put this in the custom filter? just use Name: tag:Name ??

Comment: @robby yeah `'Name': 'tag:'Name'` and `'Values': ['TestServer']`.

Comment: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'stop_instance'"

Comment: @robby I updated the working code. Tested with `python3.x`

Comment: Man Idk what the deal is on my end it still giving me errors lol. I have like 4 different versions and all are screwing up so its something im not seeing maybe a .config file or who knows. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @robby I was assuming you are running this code in lambda there you have corresponding `python3.x` runtime available and you can test.  Above is a working solution and I tested, before posting and shared the sample results  as well.

Comment: I got it to work! just had to make a few minor changes. Now I have to filter based off tags that I dont want haha but that helped for alot of my errors and helped me learn a-lot!!

Comment: @robby glad it worked out, Can you mark this question as solved. It helps the community and anyone who stumbles upon this question in the future.